# Having trouble with Ubuntu LAMP stack

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, php, mysql

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 and all the necessary packages (apache, mysql, php) using the command line. I have installed Drupal (The installation successful after a few tweaks). However after the installation, whenever I click on a link, "Not found" page pops up. Only the CMS homepage is available. Had this same issue with another CMS. BTW, the I put the CMS directories are just inside the /var/www/html/ directory (/var/www/html/drupalsite/). I tried all kind of mess with config files. Is there any basic tutorial out there? Some say I wouldn't have so many problems in another stack.

Comment: Where do the failing links go? (Hover over the link in the browser or right click and copy.)   You may need Directory or Location directives in your Apache2 configuration, or something similar in the Drual configuraion. The Apache2 is well documented on the web, or on your server if you install the documentation.  Drupal should have an installation document for Ubuntu, Debian or LInux.  Check the Apache error log as well. Your Drupal installation needs to be readable by www-data (preferably by group).

Comment: *The installation successful after a few tweaks* : worth mentioning what you did *exactly* in the question.

Comment: @BillThor thank you for your answer, I will try

Comment: @xenoid, as far as I can remember I had to manually enable php modules - that was the key issue. Other than that I tried some configs that were recommended on online forums, but which failed in my case. Also some issues with database permissions. Is there anything like to undo everything and restart? Or will that even help? Am I the only person having this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0):

Configure a MySQL User and Database:

```
mysql -u root -p
CREATE DATABASE drupal;
CREATE USER drupaluser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE,DROP,INDEX,ALTER,CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES,LOCK TABLES ON drupal.* TO drupaluser@localhost;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Install PHP Modules and Tweak the Configuration:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5-gd php5-curl libssh2-php
sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Search for the **expose_php** directive and the **allow_url_fopen** directive and set them both to "**Off**":

```
expose_php = Off
allow_url_fopen = Off
```

Enable Rewrite Functionality and Htaccess Files in Apache:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Open the default virtualhost file now:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

Within the "VirtualHost" block, add a directory block that points to our web root. Within this block, set the AllowOverride directive to "All". You may also want to add a ServerName directive to point to your domain name and change the ServerAdmin directive to reflect a valid email address:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    . . .
    ServerName  example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    . . .
</VirtualHost>

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Install the Drupal Files
Actually, we will initially unpack the files into our home directory and then copy them to the appropriate location. Doing so will give us ready access to the original files in the event that something goes wrong or in case any files are accidentally deleted later on.

Go to the Drupal download page and checkout the latest version under the "Recommended releases" section. Right click on the tar.gz link of the version you are interested and choose "copy link address" or whatever similar option your browser provides.

Back on your server, change to your home directory and use wget to download the project file using the link you copied:

```
cd ~
wget http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-7.32.tar.gz
```

Your link will likely have a different version number at the end. Once the file has been downloaded, extract the application directory by typing:

```
tar xzvf drupal*
```

Now, move into the newly extracted directory structure and use the rsync utility to safely copy all of the files into the web root directory of your server. We are using the dot in this command to specify the current directory. This is necessary in order to copy some hidden files that we need:

```
cd drupal*
sudo rsync -avz . /var/www/html
```

Now you have the original version of the files in a directory within your home folder in case you ever need to reference them. We will move into the web root directory to customize our installation:

```
cd /var/www/html
```

Adjusting the Drupal Files for Security and Ease of Installation
First, we need to make a new directory under the sub-tree sites/default called files:

```
mkdir /var/www/html/sites/default/files
```

Next, we should copy the default settings file to the filename that Drupal uses for the active configuration:

```
cp /var/www/html/sites/default/default.settings.php /var/www/html/sites/default/settings.php
```

This active settings file temporarily needs some additional permissions during the installation procedure. We need to give write permissions to the group owner for the time being (we will be assigning the group owner to the web user momentarily). We will remove this after the installation is successful:

```
chmod 664 /var/www/html/sites/default/settings.php
```

Next, we need to give group ownership of our files to the web user, which in Ubuntu is www-data. We want to give the entire Drupal installation these ownership properties:

```
sudo chown -R :www-data /var/www/html/*
```

Your server is now configured appropriately to run the web-based installation script.

Complete the Web-based Installation Procedure
However, we still need to revert the permissions for our settings file so that unauthorized users cannot make changes. On your server, restrict write access to the file by typing:

```
chmod 644 /var/www/html/sites/default/settings.php
```

[Source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-drupal-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server-with-apache)